# What is the motivation for ptrdiff_t?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, pointer-arithmetic, ptrdiff-t

Why does C define a separate type for the difference between two pointers? For example, why couldn't this be defined as `long long`, or even doing `intmax_t`? Is there ever a time when `intmax_t` does not equal `ptrdiff_t` ?

Basically, what is the meaning why this typedef (with a specific string format, etc.) is useful? And as a basic example of use, I'm doing:

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
printf("%td XXX\n", (char *)(&b) - (char *)(&a)); // 't' is formatter for prtdiff_t
```

Comment: From the standard: _When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements. **The size of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (a signed integer type) is ptrdiff_t** defined in the <stddef.h> header._

Comment: @DavidRanieri so the point of `ptrdiff_t` is to basically indicate the array-index offset? For example, '1 element', '2 elements', etc. ?

Comment: Yes, in other words:  `sizeof(a - b) == sizeof(ptrdiff_t)`

Comment: On almost any PC computer in the world (64 bit os) intmax_t is smaller then ptrdiff_t

Comment: @0___________ who said that? In almost all 64-bit platforms `intmax_t` is the same type as `ptrdiff_t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the relevant paragraph in the C Standard:

> **6.5.6 Additive operators**
> [...]
> **Semantics**
> [...]
> 9. When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (a signed integer type) is `ptrdiff_t` defined in the `<stddef.h>` header. If the result is not representable in an object of that type, the behavior is undefined. In other words, if the expressions `P` and `Q` point to, respectively, the `i`-th and `j`-th elements of an array object, the expression `(P)-(Q)` has the value `i - j` provided the value fits in an object of type `ptrdiff_t`. Moreover, if the expression `P` points either to an element of an array object or one past the last element of an array object, and the expression `Q` points to the last element of the same array object, the expression `((Q)+1)-(P)` has the same value as `((Q)-(P))+1` and as `-((P)-((Q)+1))`, and has the value zero if the expression `P` points one past the last element of the array object, even though the expression `(Q)+1` does not point to an element of the array object.<sup>108)</sup>

---

<sup>108) Another way to approach pointer arithmetic is first to convert the pointer(s) to character pointer(s): In this scheme the integer expression added to or subtracted from the converted pointer is first multiplied by the size of the object originally pointed to, and the resulting pointer is converted back to the original type. For pointer subtraction, the result of the difference between the character pointers is similarly divided by the size of the object originally pointed to.
When viewed in this way, an implementation need only provide one extra byte (which may overlap another object in the program) just after the end of the object in order to satisfy the “one past the last element” requirements.</sup>

Although the C Standard does not mandate this, `ptrdiff_t` is usually defined as the signed integer type with the same size as `size_t`.  On architectures where the maximum size of an object is limited to 32 bits, such as 32-bit Windows and Unix systems, `size_t` is an unsigned 32-bit integer type and `ptrdiff_t` a signed 32-bit integer type, whereas on 64-bit systems with a larger address space, they both are 64-bit integer types, signed for `ptrdiff_t` and unsigned for `size_t`.

Note however that the difference of 2 pointers into a very large array of `char` may exceed the range of the signed type with the same size as `size_t`. For example a 3GB char array may be available on a 32-bit system (`UINT32_MAX` > 3GB) but the difference of 2 pointers can be as large as 3GB in absolute value, which exceeds the range of `int32_t`, hence does *fit* in the `ptrdiff_t` type of this platform, invoking undefined behavior.

Most implementations obtain the difference by subtracting the addresses and dividing the result by the element size, using signed arithmetics or signed right shift if the size is a power of 2. This may produce an incorrect result for large arrays of elements larger than `char` **even** if the value fits in an object of type `ptrdiff_t`.

The rationale for using an implementation defined type `ptrdiff_t` and not `long long` is to keep compatibility with existing implementations and avoid using larger types on systems with a smaller address space, where this would cause extra overhead in both space and time. In early C implementations, the type `int` was used for this purpose and when `size_t` was introduced with a potentially different range than `unsigned int`, a specific type for the difference of 2 pointers became necessary as `int` was too small. `ptrdiff_t` may still be too small but only for border cases.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there ever a time when `intmax_t` does not equal `ptrdiff_t` ?

Yes, on 32-bit platforms where pointers are 32-bit, and `intmax_t` is >=64-bit.

Comment: what would be an example of a platform that is like that?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 some examples are 32-bit platforms as mentioned in the answer. Anyway `ptrdiff_t` has existed long before C99 where `intmax_t` was introduced

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 Literally any 32-bit Windows/Linux/...?

Comment: @DavidRanieri Just downloaded x32 MinGW from MSYS2 to test it. `ptrdiff_t` is 32-bit, `intmax_t` is 64-bit. Which makes sense, since `long long` is required to be at least 64 bits.